# How to filter a data.Frame using a String in another table?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

So, when I type to see the first element of a table I get the following.

```
>names(freq25)[1] 
"japão"
```

When I type

```
>library(dplyr)
>filter(data, grepl("japão", HeadLine)) %>% select(Column)
Correct table
```

I get the correct table. But If I put both together I get:

```
>filter(data, grepl(names(freq25)[1], Headline)) %>% select(Column)
[1] Column 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I get an empty table.

I imagine the class of names() is not appropriate for the function grepl. But then I tried

```
>class(names(freq)[1])
[1] "character"
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Any advice?

Ps: I want to filter using names(freq25)[i] because I want to filter a number of times, one per element in freq25. Maybe I could do that using something else.

Edit1: Content of freq25

```
>str(freq25)
 Named num [1:25] 1260 304 215 193 192 167 164 151 150 149 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:25] "japão" "anos" "japonês" "tóquio" ...

>freq25
   japão         anos      japonês       tóquio        preso        homem        tokyo    japoneses      polícia 
    1260          304          215          193          192          167          164          151          150 
   maior          dia        sobre     previsão         após        parte     japonesa          mil       mulher 
     149          136          134          131          129          128          117          113          112 
  brasil estrangeiros        tempo      pessoas      governo         novo         pode 
     108          107          100           97           95           93           90
```

Comment: Do you think you can share the content of `freq25`?

Comment: I just included in the question

Comment: I think `names(freq25)[1]` gives you `"japão"`.

Comment: yes, it does. I said "word"to be generic, but let me fix that too.

Comment: I see, can you show `data` too then?